# What is the meaning of this cliche: "purest form"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

[image: Picture of a book page]

> Although most of us have the potential to lead others, 9s can demonstrate leadership **in its purest form**-leadership by example.

Here, I did not understand clearly, *"purest form"* ?

I don't understand leadership is "pure"? Leader can be great, "Pure" word, it does not match, maybe..

Comment: When you looked up "purest" and "form" in the dictionary, why didn't that help you understand the phrase? If you [edit] your question to explain why it's difficult to get the meaning just from the definitions, I think it would help you get a good answer.

Comment: I think, Purest form is a scientific word..Can you read me synonym for this cliche (sentente)? Maybe I understand...

Comment: Aside: "cliche" and "idiom" don't mean exactly the same thing. "Cliche" implies a phrase that is so over-used that using it indicates lack of careful thought by the speaker.

Comment: You can edit my question, because english is my second language, I 'm so sorry..

Comment: It is not a cliche nor an idiom. Consider "purest form" as "the most pure form". In this case: the most pure form of leadership is leadership by example.

Comment: I dont understand **leadership is "pure"**? Leader can be great, "Pure" word, it does not match, maybe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language of the texts suggests that the leadership provided by most people is ***adulterated*** by lesser things (self-interest, power-seeking, hypocrisy, or whatever).  On the other hand, leadership that is not contaminated by these other things (and is therefore pure) consists of leading by setting an example.

Note that the text does not say the ***leader*** is pure, but that the ***leadership*** is pure.  As you say, a leader may be great, but we do not normally call him or her pure in this context.  Pure normally means something else, like moral/sexual purity, when applied to a person.  However, a person may demonstrate ***pure leadership*** by not allowing other things to pervert their leadership.  In this context we may also use "in its best form" as a substitute.

One might also demonstrate generosity or any other attribute in its purest form---unadulterated by lesser things.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the phrase "in its purest form" is a translation of the Latin **"per se"** (by itself) or "not mixed with anything else."

Comment: Thank you for answer. I do not understand the meaning of the sentence. Although most of us have the potential to lead others, 9s can demonstrate leadership in its ***purest form***-leadership by example. Can you replace it with synonym?

Comment: The most effective way to lead other people is to give them an example, to act yourself.

Comment: General synonym: **unadulterated.**  Another for this case would be **in its best form.**